# Проблемы с кодировкой в подключаемом скрипте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Главная страница:

- прописан `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
  charset=utf-8">`;
- файл(и все скрипты что подключены) кодированы в UTF-8(без BOM);
- страничка запускается через Денвер(слышал что там бывают странные проблемы).

Весь контент страницы отображается нормально, но только один скрипт отображается иероглифами. Я десяток раз его перекодировал туда и обратно и добавлял `<script src="" charset="utf-8"></script>`, но без результатов.

В скрипте генерируется серия `<div>` в которых может быть разный текст. Процесс выглядит так:

```
for (i=0;i<$(".bgtxt div").length;i++) {
    $(".bgtxt div:eq("+i+")").append(randslang());
}
```

Функция `randslang()` просто вытаскивает по одному случайному слову из массива.

В чем может быть проблема, что добавить в тему для решения вопроса?

Comment: где именно скрипт отображается иероглифами?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, окей, я исправил баги денвера, теперь все работает, но... Теперь все в иероглифах. Не подскажете что нужно что бы чисто html страничка правильно отображалась? Мета-тег прописан.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, в плане чисто html страничку видно правильно, но если открывать ее через `http://sitename/index.html` то будет проблема, почему так?